# Error al llamar una función desde otra función en la misma clase

Tags: php, poo

```
<?php  
class algo 
{

    public function haceralgo1(){
        $num1=1;
        $num2=1;

        $resultado = $this->haceralgo2($num1,$num2);
        return $resultado;
    }

    public function haceralgo2($num1,$num2){
        $result = $num1 +$num2;
        return $result;
    }
}

$mostrar = algo::haceralgo1();
echo $mostrar;?>
```

si tengo el codigo anterior ¿porque ha de salir este error?

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\SOAP\sumaclass.php:9 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\SOAP\sumaclass.php(19): algo::haceralgo1() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\SOAP\sumaclass.php on line 9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estás creando mal la *instancia* del *objeto* `algo`, deberías corregir tu código de la siguiente forma:

```
$algo = new algo;
$mostrar = $algo->haceralgo1(); 
echo $mostrar;
```

No puedes acceder al método `haceralgo1();` mediante `::` porque no es una función estática, por eso debes usar el operador `->`

Answer (score 3):

muchisimas gracias a todos por sus respuestas !

```
<?php  
class algo 
{

    public function haceralgo1(){
        $num1=1;
        $num2=1;

        $resultado = self::haceralgo2($num1,$num2);
        return $resultado;
    }

    public function haceralgo2($num1,$num2){
        $result = $num1 +$num2;
        return $result;
    }
}

$mostrar =  new algo;
$imprimir = $mostrar->haceralgo1();
echo $imprimir;?>
```

se los agradezco enorme mente ! feliz tarde(noche) a todos!

Answer (score 1):

En la linea 19 con el operador `"::"` haces llamar a un método de clase estático, para usarlo de esa manera tendrías que cambiar el código de las funciones.

```
public static function haceralgo1(){
        $num1=1;
        $num2=1;

        $resultado = self::haceralgo2($num1,$num2);
        return $resultado;
    }

    public static function haceralgo2($num1,$num2){
        $result = $num1 +$num2;
        return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que te sucedes, es que no estas llamando a la instancia. Te dejo el ejemplo como tienes que llamarlo:

> Así es como se inicia la clase: **$alg = new  alrgo();** y **$alg** es un objeto, que para llamar a cada una de las funciones de tu clase, solo tienes que hacer **$alg->nombre de la funcion**

```
$alg = new  alrgo();
$mostrar = $alg->haceralgo1();
echo $mostrar;
```